# Feedback on Proving Quasi-concave Composite Functions

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, convex-analysis

I am struggling to feel confident I fulfilled all the steps of the following proof. "Let f : R → R be quasiconcave and g : R → R be increasing. Show that
f ◦g is quasiconcave."

My Steps:

- Let z=λx+(1-λ)y where λ∈[0,1].
- Since *g* is an increasing function, it can be seen g(x)>g(z)>g(y).
- if g(z)=z', g(x)=x' and g(y)=y' then we can find that consider that
  z'=g(λx+(1-λ)y)=λ'x'+(1-λ)'y'>=λx'+(1-λ)y'
- Since f is quasi-concave we can see that f(z')>min{f(x'),f(y')}.

My concern are the steps taken in bullet point 3. I believe it is clear that if g is an increasing function, then it makes sense that g(λx)>=λ(g(x)) and the rest follows.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).